# "Multi-tasked woman" vs "Multitasking woman"

Tags: word-usage, usage

When talking about a woman (or even man) who makes a lot of tasks at the same time, what's more appropriate or more common between the following sentences?

> You are **multi-tasked** woman.

> You are **multitasking** woman.

Google shows more than 50K results for [multitasking woman](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=**multitasking**%20woman&oq=**multitasking**%20woman&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22multitasking%20woman%22), and a few hundreds results for [multi-tasked](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=**multitasking**%20woman&oq=**multitasking**%20woman&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22multi%20TASKED%20woman%22). I wonder how a noun could be used as an adjective.

Comment: On the _NOW Corpus_, I find just 44 sentences using _multi-tasked_; in most cases, it is used as verb. There is also _He is a multi-tasked and multi-talented individual._ though. I am not sure it means the same as _He is a multi-tasking and multi-talented individual._

Comment: As for using nouns as attributive, that is common enough in English. Think of _school bus_, _family house_, etc.

Comment: Both could be OK, but one would sound like the woman herself is [a multi-tasker (i.e., multitasking) herself](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1816916/295581311/stock-vector-multitasking-super-mom-concept-with-woman-holding-baby-and-housework-objects-in-hands-vector-295581311.jpg) and the other would sound like she is [made to be multi-tasked](http://b-i.forbesimg.com/worldviews/files/2013/12/tags.jpg) because of extenuating circumstances (i.e., multitasked).

Comment: I would be careful about the phrase "makes a lot of tasks at the same time" - I suspect you mean that she works on or completes a lot of tasks as the same time, which is different to "making" (or creating) those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

To me, there is a subtle difference in meaning here:

> You are **multi-tasked** woman.

This states that the woman often/always has multiple tasks simultaneously assigned to her for completion, whether or not she is capable of doing so, whereas:

> You are **multitasking** woman.

is a statement that the woman in question is currently in the act of completing multiple tasks at once, which carries some implication that she is capable of doing so. Furthermore, this may have been intended as:

> You are [a] **multitasking** woman.

which would imply to me that the woman in question is seen to have some tangible capability to handle multiple tasks at once.